# Does anyone know how to solve this ODE $y = x(y')^2+(y')^3$?

Tags: calculus

$$y = x(y')^2+(y')^3$$

I tried many ways like differentiating it again or dividing it by $y$, et cetera; still I don’t get the answer. I will appreciate it, if you could give me some advice.

Comment: It would be a good idea if you added details about exactly what methods you tried.

Comment: there are two main method I tried one is differentiate both side and then change of variables y'=z, then rearrange and found cannot use integrate factor; Another one is dividing both side by y' and then continue to solve it which also can not work out. The solution I got using matlab is either y=0 or y=x+1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y'=p$,
$$y = x(y')^2+(y')^3 \implies y=xp^2+p^3$$
Yes, go ahead and differentiate the equation w.r.t. $x$, then
$$p=p^2+2pxp'+3p^2p'x+ \implies (p-p^2)dx-(2xp+3p^2)dp=0$$
This is like $Mdx+Ndp=0$ an inexact ODE because $\frac{\partial M}{\partial p}=1-2p,\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=-2p$ are unequal. Then the integrating factor is $$I=\exp\frac{ \int \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}- \frac{\partial M}{\partial p}}{M}dx=\exp\int(p(p-1))^{-1}dp=(p-1)/p.$$
Multiplying the ODE by $I$, we get the exact ODE as
$$-(p-1)^2dx-(2x-3p)(p-1)dp=0$$
Its solution is given as $$\int -(p-1)^2 dx\text{[treat $p$ as a constant]}+\int \text{terms of $N$ not containing $x$} dp=C$$
$$ -(p-1)^2 x + \int 3p(p-1) dp=C \implies -(p-1)^2x+p^3-3p^2/2$$
We get $$ x=\frac{2p^3-3p^2-2C}{2(p-1)^2}.$$
Next, from the first eq, we get
$$y=p^2\left(\frac{2p^3-3p^2-2C}{2(p-1)^2}+p\right)$$
The last two equations constitute the solution of the ODE which is a parametric eq. of a family of curves where $p$ acts as parameter.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but you haven't solve p which is y'. The solution I got using matlab is either 0 or y=x+1 and we can easily check these two solution are correct.

Comment: When you get x and y in terms of p, t or whatever you have got  the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You may select the answer now.